# How to return just the value with sql inside shell script?

Tags: shell, sqlplus

The code below is returning:

EMAIL -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- email@email.com

case "$type" in

```
                2)
                echo "Type is outbound: $type"
                        contact=$(sqlplus -s ${SQLPLUS_INFO} <<EOF
                        SELECT email FROM table WHERE email = 'x';
                        exit
                        EOF)
                        echo
                        echo $contact
                        echo
                ;;

                1)
                echo "Type is inbound: $type"
                ;;
        esac
```

But I just would like:

EMAIL -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- email@email.com

Any help please?

Comment: What you want and what you get is the same. what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sqlplus command `set pagesize 0` turns off column headers and other pagination stuff.

```
case "$type" in
    2)  echo "Type is outbound: $type"
        contact=$(sqlplus -s ${SQLPLUS_INFO} <<EOF
            set pagesize 0
            SELECT email FROM table WHERE email = 'x';
            exit
EOF
        )
        printf "\n%s\n\n" "$contact"
    ;;
```

This page is a useful reference: http://ss64.com/ora/syntax.html

Comment: it worked, thanks!
thanks also for the reference provided! will check!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you put ) after the EOF statement.

EOF should always come alone!

Fix your script by putting the ) on a new line.

```
...
exit
EOF
)
echo
...
```

Comment: @LeandroToshioTakeda, also ensure that you have no whitespace before or after "EOF"

Comment: Did not work also @glenn jackman, I also tried to remove the tabs, same result:

EMAIL -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- email@email.com

EMAIL is the table column name, not sure what is the many ---, and the email@email.com is the value from the table, the one I want.